# Drupal button added with form alter leads to fatal error in common.inc

Tags: drupal-7, form-api

I'm using a form alter in Drupal 7 to add another button to the node form:

```
function mymod_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form[$key]['button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Seach),
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
    '#submit' => array('mymod_process'),
  );
 }

...
...

function mymod_process(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;    
  // Do my processing here...
}
```

I've added `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;` to keep the form values when the button is pushed. The first time I press the button this works, the second time I press my custom button, it gives me the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot create references to/from string offsets nor overloaded objects in /www/includes/common.inc on line 6430
```

Then when I reload the page, drupal_set_message() reports the following:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in drupal_attributes() (line 2298 of /www/includes/common.inc).
```

If I take out `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;`, the error goes away. But then the form values are not preserved. Any ideas how I can preserve my form values without hitting this error?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem where I've put `'#limit_validation_errors' => array(),` and the form values where not being preserved. If you take that line out, the form values actually do get preserved.

See [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#limit_validation_errors):

> This is normally used in multistep forms in the case of a "back" button, for example, where **'#limit_validation_errors' => array()** would mean not to validate anything as **form values on the current page are to be discarded anyway**.